# How to test a controller with streamed content with MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, outputstream, mockmvc

I'd like to test a Spring controller, without Spring context, with **MockMvc**.
This controller **streams** the content by writing it in the **OutputStream** of the response.

Here is the controller code:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/file")
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.json");
    ObjectWriter objectWriter = new ObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).writer();

    Item item = new Item();
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(item);

    try (Writer bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()))) {
        objectWriter.writeValue(bufferedWriter, items);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```java
@Test
public void getFile_ok() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get(END_POINT + "/file").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
           .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

This controller works well, but the unit test fails with an IOException:

```java
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(BufferedWriter.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:126)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:253)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `objectWriter.writeValue(bufferedWriter, items);` tries to close the stream.

Javadoc:

> Note: method does not close the underlying stream explicitly here;
>   however, JsonFactory this mapper uses may choose to close the stream
>   depending on its settings (by default, it will try to close it when
>   JsonGenerator we construct is closed).

In runtime, it doesn't close it but in my tests, it does, and the next line `bufferedWriter.flush();` just sends the `IOEception`.

So to fix it I added a try/catch this way:

```
try {
    writer.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.info("Stream closed in writeValue()", e);
}
```